# iphone: how to detect last caller number programmatically?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to detect last caller number & call duration on iPhone, I am able to get all notification (Core Telephony) but don't know how to get caller number.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, the API will not allow you to do this.

I think apple will never allow this due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 1):

According to api you cant do it... but here something which might help you ... though I haven't tried it myself...
http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Answer (score 0):

Apple officially don't allow.You cann't access the database of the other application then your one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if ([name isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"])
    {
        // CTCallCenter *center = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
        // center.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call) {
        // NSLog(@”call:%@”, [call description]);
        // };

        //NSDictionary *info = (NSDictionary *)userInfo;
        CTCall *call = (CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
        NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
        NSLog(@"caller:%@",caller);
        //CTCallDisconnect(call);
        /* or one of the following functions: CTCallAnswer
         CTCallAnswerEndingActive
         CTCallAnswerEndingAllOthers
         CTCallAnswerEndingHeld
         */

        //if ([caller isEqualToString:@"+1555665753"])
        if ([caller isEqualToString:@"+918740061911"])
        {
            NSLog(@"disconnecting call");
            //disconnect this call
            CTCallDisconnect(call);

        }

    }
```