# Can I track number called, time called and duration on an iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone: how to detect last caller number programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552715/iphone-how-to-detect-last-caller-number-programmatically)

I am interested in writing an iphone app that would check all the numbers called from the phone and query a cloud hosted database.  If the number being called matched a number in the database, then the app would write call data such as number called, time of call, and duration  to the database.  I am not an iphone developer and am just wondering if this would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. At least on a non-jailbroken iPhone. Apple (thankfully) does not allow access to this data for 3rd party apps.